# selection constraint is plsql

Tags: sql, select, plsql

Assume I have a table **entries** with columns: **id**, **alias_one**, **alias_two**, **name**.

How do I select all values from **entries** where there exists several **names** for the same **alias_one** / **alias_two** pairs provided that **names** are not known?

Looks like as an option, group by **alias_one** and **alias_two** can be used but somehow it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return all table rows for which there's another row with the same alias_one and alias_two but different name.

```
select
  id,
  alias_one,
  alias_two,
  name
from
  (
  select
    id,
    alias_one,
    alias_two,
    name,
    count (distinct name) over (partition by alias_one, alias_two) as cnt
  from entries
  )
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to

```
GROUP BY ALIAS_ONE||ALIAS_TWO
```

OR

```
GROUP BY ALIAS_ONE||ALIAS_TWO
HAVING COUNT(ALIAS_ONE||ALIAS_TWO) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok, I think I understand now. Try this:

```
select * from entries e where (alias_one,alias_two) in (select alias_one, alias_two
from entries group by alias_one, alias_two having count(distinct name) > 1)
```

Comment: That doesn't clear up anything for me. I assumed the names are what you want to get, so obviously they're not known.